# What "enhanced" abilities does Dr. Julian Bashir show after S5:E16?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-ds9

In episode S05:E16 of DS9, "Doctor Bashir, I Presume", it is revealed that Dr. Julian Bashir was

> genetically enhanced at the age of six to have heightened intelligence, hand/eye coordination, stamina, vision, reflexes, weight, height, etc.

At the end of the episode he throws a near-perfect dart game and Chief O'Brien jokes about having to handicap him in future games.

Following that episode, I know that there was an episode where Bashir calculated a number before the computer could... **but what other "enhanced" abilities did Bashir show on-screen?**

Comment: “Chief O'Brien jokes about having to handicap him in future games” — _that’s no joke_.

Answer (score 14):

He displays a few of them in [S7:E23 - Extreme Measures](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Extreme_Measures_(episode)).  Some of them are perhaps just reflections of his intellect, but at least one isn't.

- O'brien finds Julian in Quark's late at night, and when O'brien asks how he got in he says "The lock isn't very complex."  This despite the fact that we know this lock was created by Rom, and was supposed to be, in fact, rather impressive.
- Same scene, Julian says he was pondering that night how many people must have been involved in a conspiracy, and says he came up with at least 73 people ranging from clerks to admirals.  He can work out, in a matter of hours, complex organizational needs and minimal contingencies for a sophisticated conspiracy.
- Julian needs to make significant changes to his dive plans, requiring O'Brien to make significant numbers of technical changes (rerouting power relays, getting new devices, etc.).  O'Brien says he can't guarantee anything will work without running a ton of diagnostic programs first.  Julian says he's already run the diagnostics.  In his head.
- Precise, conscious control over his vital signs.  He very explicitly says this is one of the benefits of being genetically engineered.  He had set things up so that the system would automatically pull him out of the dive when he raised his blood pressure by 40%.
- Precise measurement of time down to the second (at least). O'Brien states at one point that he has no idea how long they've been in Sloan's mind, and Julian responds "23 minutes, 11 seconds".

Answer (score 3):

In the books (Mission Gamma series), Dr Bashir has been noted to have perfect memory recall making use of a Mind Palace technique for remembering. Also a little story was given about how he missed the top spot of his medical class graduation by purposely getting one question wrong.

Comment: Hello and welcome to SFF! While this answer may be correct it would be better to add sources to back up your claims.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot - Thank you for the reminder about references, I should know better. I removed the '4 hour sleep' part until I get time to find the episode.

Comment: I recall his missing the top spot being discussed in two DS9 episodes; at least one of them theorized that he *subconsciously* missed one question, possibly due to having a crush on the woman who took the top spot.

Comment: @RDFozz I believe the episode where Bashir is subjected to a psychic assault and has to navigate his own consciousness to survive includes lines concerning his intentionally missing that question.

Comment: @zibadawatimmy - No argument - the two episodes I was thinking of were much earlier, long before we discovered his status as genetically enhanced. Once one comes to the conclusion that one has subconsciously intentionally missed a question, then one has intentionally missed the question, and may skip the subconsciously part in future discussion. Of course, given the change to the character, the intentional miss may be something he was doing consciously, but hiding the reason for.